# Handle SQLAlchemy disconnect

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy for my Flask application and I have just ran into a few problems with closed connection to my MySQL DB.

I'm setting up my connection like this in my `__init__.py`

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@localhost/db', pool_recycle=3600)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

(I am using both ways to query my DB)

I have just added the pool_recycle setting but I would like to be sure a lost connection can be restarted.

Reading the following section:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic

I'm not really sure how to actually use this code, I don't want have to check the connection every time its being used in the code but rather have the connection restarted if it would close down. Is it possible to add a general event to handle DB disconnections?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that app itself only knows if connection is down when it tries to use it. It's as if you're logged in a website but after refresh your session is dead thus asking to log in again. Until you refresh - you're logged in. Schrodinger's cat?

I've just ran into the very same problem. So far it seems that using pool_recycle is the way to go and if the error occurs then lover recycle time or edit configs of mySQL.

As the documentation implies - ether you check regularly, or expect an error (like in Java, just try: except: everything within classes methods and use those) or just refresh from time to time in all hopes that connection is up. In this case pessimistic approach does implement checking regularly before you're using database. It's the safest way but as you mentioned - quite dirty one.

Another option to do as Django - simply don't have persistent connections. Sure it's quite a lot slower, but if project is smaller - it should do the job. About it: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool

Answer (score 1):

is better use sqlalchemy with poolclass=NullPoll(not persistent connections) on proyects with hight traffic since there are so much connections concurrents

for my expirience i always use slqalchemy with this feature