# Sqlalchemy loses connection during query

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project that combines a few data sources based around registered users. One query in particular is giving me a lot of problems:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# of course, the info here is obscured
prod_engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://password@host:3306/database',pool_timeout=3600,pool_recycle=3600)

query_users = """
SELECT users.id,
CASE
    WHEN ((users.role = '' OR users.role IS NULL) AND users.plan LIKE 'pro%') OR users.role REGEXP '(pro|agent|manager)' THEN 'professional' ELSE 'consumer'
END AS 'modified_role',
users.created_at,
users.logged_in_at AS 'last_login',
COUNT(DISTINCT(folders.id)) AS 'folder_count',
IF(COUNT(DISTINCT(folders.id)) > 1, '2 or more','0 to 1') AS 'folder_group',
MIN(folders.created_at) AS 'first_folder_created',
MAX(folders.created_at) AS 'last_folder_created'
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN folders
ON folders.created_by = users.id
AND folders.discarded = 0
AND folders.created_at >= '2010-11-30 23:59:59'
WHERE users.invalid_email IS NULL
GROUP BY 1"""

users = pd.read_sql_query(query_users, prod_engine)
```

No matter what I've tried, I get this error (almost always within three seconds, sometimes instantly).

```
InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I've tried a few things, like adding the `pool_timeout` and `pool_recycle` options to the `create_engine` function per the docs here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

I also tried `users = pd.read_sql_query(query_folder_users, prod_engine,chunksize=10000)` but get the same error.

The interesting thing is this query works fine whenever I run it in Sequel Pro; it starts returning rows immediately and only takes ~10 seconds to finish completely. The output is about 550,000 rows.

There are number of other threads/posts I've found, but none seems to quite address what I need:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/TWL7aWab9ww
[Handle SQLAlchemy disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475001/handle-sqlalchemy-disconnect)
http://blog.fizyk.net.pl/blog/reminder-set-pool_recycle-for-sqlalchemys-connection-to-mysql.html

Reading the docs here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-lost-connection.html, I noticed this line:

> Sometimes the “during query” form happens when millions of rows are
>   being sent as part of one or more queries. If you know that this is
>   happening, you should try increasing net_read_timeout from its default
>   of 30 seconds to 60 seconds or longer, sufficient for the data
>   transfer to complete.

Seems like I might need to change this option, but I cannot find anything in the SQLAlchemy docs that mentions this.

Has anyone run into this problem before? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Does that query work when using a different method (e.g. a GUI sql manager)? Have you tried a different DBAPI other than `mysqlconnector` (e.g. `pymysql`, check [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#dialect-mysql) for your options)?

Comment: Yes, works fine with Sequel Pro http://www.sequelpro.com. Haven't tried mymysql though.

Comment: Try with another DBAPI: for pymysql you can download it by running `conda install pymysql` in terminal (or pip if you don't have Anaconda), and then just replacing `mysqlconnector` with `pymysql` in your `create_engine` string.

Comment: Just tried this exactly as your wrote but now ran into a new problem: "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string" (?) I'm using the same exact code, just swapped out mysqlconnector for pymysql instead :-/

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL server's `max_allowed_packet_size` variable and increase it. Most of the time when MySQL drops the connection during a query it's because the payload was too big.